# Draw a new curve for each level curve with specific slope in QGIS

Tags: qgis, slope

I´m new to QGIS due to a project I´m involved in.
For this project we want to draw a new curve for each level curve, but with a 0.5% positive slope for the valleys and 0.5% negative slope for the hills.

I managed to get the curves and inclination map. I also found a way to draw lines or polygons close to the curves. But I can´t find a way to perform this task on an 'automatic' way.

Could please somebody give me a clue on how to do it?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: I ain't got no bloody idea what you're trying to do. Can you provide examples of your current data and you desired output?

Comment: The idea is to create gpx routes around the curves with +0.5% slope in valleys and -0.5 slope in hills. So, for that, I want to use the information of the level curves and add or substract 0.5% slope. This is used for the "keyline" irrigation system but as long as I know it is normally done by hand. In this project I would like to do something more automated